# How to avoid TypeError: Cannot read property 'picture' of undefined in React Native?

Tags: react-native, typeerror

this.props.navigation.state.params.picture is throwing `TypeError: Cannot read property 'picture' of undefined`

I want to check if it is readable or not.

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      let varPicPath = this.props.navigation.state.params.picture;
      if (typeof varPicPath === 'undefined') {
        console.warn('hi' + varPicPath);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
    }
  };
```

if i write `let varPicPath;` instead of `let varPicPath = this.props.navigation.state.params.picture;` then `console.warn` prints `hi undefined`

Hope you're getting the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try somethinhg like this :

```
      let picture = '';
        if(this.props.navigation.state.params) {
          picture = this.props.navigation.state.params.picture;
        }
        return picture;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      let varPicPath = this.props.navigation.state.params == null ? null: this.props.navigation.state.params.picture;
      if (typeof varPicPath == null) {
        console.warn('hi' + varPicPath);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: componentDidMount exceed maximum .... I got something like that.